# on converting pdf into image the images are fading out

Tags: image, pdf, pdfrenderer

I am having the high quality image in pdf and when converting this into image, the images are fading out.(using jar file PDFRENDER 0.9.1) i having the image in pdf form like this
[image]

and after converting this into image, the image is shown as

[image]

I am getting an error

Unsupported function type 4.
    at com.sun.pdfview.function.FunctionType4.parse(FunctionType4.java:828)
    at com.sun.pdfview.function.PDFFunction.getFunction(PDFFunction.java:168)
    at com.sun.pdfview.colorspace.PDFColorSpace.getColorSpace(PDFColorSpace.java:176)
    at com.sun.pdfview.pattern.PDFShader.getShader(PDFShader.java:144)
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFParser.doShader(PDFParser.java:1145)
    at com.sun.pdfview.PDFParser.iterate(PDFParser.java:633)
    at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

So what is the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, there is an **Unsupported function type 4** in the OP's PDF, somewhere in the context of some shader colorspace definition.

> A type 4 function (PDF 1.3), also called a PostScript calculator function, shall be represented as a stream containing code written in a small subset of the PostScript language.
>
> *([ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 7.10.5)*

It looks like PDFRENDER 0.9.1 does not support (some) such type 4 functions. Thus one either has to refrain from using them or switch to a different PDF renderer.

Unfortunately the OP has not shared the PDF (unless I overlooked it). So I can neither test other renderers nor check where exactly that function is used.

Comment: so how can i overcome from this problem, any other pdfrender is their which can help to correct the image

Comment: @programmer There well might be other renderers which can properly handle those *PostScript calculator functions*; they may not be available for free, though. As you have not shared the PDF in question, only you can test them.